# Help with identifying patterns or cryptographic implement

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash

While I'm pen testing, I came across these values mapping to a store ID. These values are gathered across three different accounts.

```
0015400000jpjcEAAQ
0015400000jrjH7AAI
0015400000jtDS9AAM
```

It's not a hash or base64. It doesn't look encrypted either as there are 10-bytes static values. The last 8-bytes tho, what can I deduce from this?

Comment: This isn't a security question. At best, it's a reverse engineering question.

Comment: Oh sorry! where should I post this to?